# Altering an instance NSArray

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have an instance array that I will end up changing depending on user settings. I set the to a immutable NSArray:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *pointArray;
```

When i need to change the array, i've been doing this:

```
-(void)changePointArray
{
    NSMutableArray *tempArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.pointArray];

    // Make changes

    self.pointArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:tempArray];
}
```

Is this acceptable practice or am i creating a leak? Should i just typecast it instead:

```
self.pointArray = (NSArray *)tempArray;
```

or do even need to worry about setting a NSMutableArray to a NSArray?

```
self.pointArray = tempArray;
```

Comment: Have you tried [self.pointArray mutableCopy]?

Comment: You are not leaking as `arrayWithArray` returns an autoreleased object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no leak (with respect to memory management).

Your code is absolutely ok if your goal is to not expose the mutual array in your public interface.

If, however, you don't care about abstraction here (or if that property is not public), it would be easier to just declare the property of type `NSMutualArray *` in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

What are your concerns?  For such a scenario one might be concerned with atomicity, security against someone else modifying the array, neither, or both.  If you're concerned with neither, just make your property an NSMutableArray and modify it in place.

If you're worried about atomicity, you should make a copy, modify the copy, then swap it in (but, of course, all users of the object must know to make their own private copy of the *pointer* for a series of "atomic" references, vs re-referencing the property for each reference).

For security you should both make the array an immutable NSArray and make the property read-only.

Comment: Yep, i wasn't sure if using an instance mutable array was a taboo or not so i did a quick google search. Found a couple people recommending for these reasons to make in immutable. Didn't think about making it also read-only. TBH, i don't need to worry about atomicity with this program, but i figured it would be good practice.

Comment: @Log139 - Of course, "security" doesn't really matter for 99% of apps, since a small group of people have access to all the source and can change anything.  And Objective-C is not really "secure" in the way Java is anyway.  "Security" really only prevents accidental modification and "Gee, I really should do it the 'right' way, but I don't have the time" modifications.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to worry about this `self.pointArray = tempArray;` because `NSMutableArray` is a subclass of `NSArray`. Maybe a little bit more memory is allocated for `NSMutableArray` but that is not a problem at all - don't worry about that.

And of course you still can do `self.pointArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:tempArray];`

You would have problems in the opposite case though if you had

`@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *pointArray;`

and you were trying to do `self.pointArray = tempArray;` were tempArray is `NSArray*`

and if you try to do `self.pointArray = (NSMutableArray*)tempArray;` IN THAT CASE you would have problems

Answer (score 0):

If the content can be changed or modified then the best solution is to use an `NSMutableArray` instead of `NSArray`.

If you have any specific reason for using `NSArray` then the following code is the best solution.

```
self.pointArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:tempArray];
```